# Why this keyword can not be replaced with other things?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am learning web designing these days, but in this code, I tried to replace `this` keyword with `acc[i]`, but why the program can't run like before?!

Why can't I replace `this` keyword with `acc[i]`?! Is it unreasonable? why?

```
var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
this.classList.toggle("active");
```

In two lines above I can't do this
    https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion

Comment: Where is acc[i] declared? show all your code

Comment: this refers to the owner object or  refers to the element  which event is triggered

Comment: here [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp)

Comment: You mean in the callback function right? Because script runs just ones and adds an event listener to an element and when you call these callback with a click acc is not defined anymore there is only this reference for that element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You cannot replace `this` keyword with `acc[i]` because at the end of the loop, the variable `i` will be assigned with the last value that loop receives. So whenever an event happens in some other element , the `acc[i]` would point to the last element and not the actual element on which the event occured.

Comment: You mean that "i" in acc[i] is 3 in this code, right? I mean that acc[i] is acc[3], because acc[i] variable only will be assigned with the last value of i (3), and so with acc[3] there is nothing we can do,  true?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replace this to `acc[i]` then you have to use `a[i-1]` because array starts from zero

here is full js code

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    acc[i-1].classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

working demo link

https://jsfiddle.net/er51xcqs/

Answer (score 0):

You can't use acc[i] because you are first adding an event of click to each of "acc" elements, and when the event is triggered you need to have the exact reference of the item you clicked and keyword "this" provides you that reference. If you user acc[i] instead, the i variable by now has the value 3, and acc[3] doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

you actually create a callback function there to be triggered on clicking acc[i]. So it cannot access acc[i] from inside the function as you don't send it while calling the function.